# I asked 1 question in total, it has 4 upvotes, 3 answers, 0 flags. How can I have a history of asking low quality questions?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Day 4: Dom kindly provided some background information as he/she stated in the comments. The moderation still claims that both accounts are mine, but I've had only 1 account. On top of that, depending on the information Dom provided, the other 'orhan torun' was abusive. I'm a member of stackexhange for 14 months (approximately) and I haven't been abusive to anyone. Either on the internet or face-to-face, I hate being abusive and I'm against behave like a 'bully'. I publicly claim that the 'abusive' orhan torun is not me. What if a 3rd 'orhan torun' will appear? The system is neither fair nor logical.

Day 3: The problem still continues and I still haven't informed about the reason.

This is the one and only question I asked: [consonant skips in 2nd species counterpoint](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/124375/consonant-skips-in-2nd-species-counterpoint)

And when I clicked 'ask questions' a few minutes ago, this is what I get

> You have a history of asking low quality questions. Please put more thought, time, and effort into your questions. To help you do this, the number of questions you may ask per week is currently limited. For more information, visit the Help Center.

I don't think there is a logical explanation for that. It's hard to understand why mods or a mod made this decision. How can I have a history of asking low quality questions?

Regardless of the upvotes and answers contributed, this is not a low quality question. But to make my statement more 'rational', I focused on upvotes and answers. I didn't even ask question**s** the number is 1 which is not plural.

Comment: I'm sending this case to a CM to look at more, but I think it may stem from a previous account you had on the site. Also no current bans on questions or answers seem to be on your account.

Comment: I didn't create an account before on music stackexchange. This is the first and only one. could you provide more information about that please?

Comment: According to the logs I have it's not, but this is also the first time I've seen a past account linked period. I'm not able to share more details, but maybe a CM can give more info.

Comment: Interesting the logs you have. Are you mentioning e-mail address logs, IP logs or something else? One can creat one account with one e-mail address and it's not possible to link my account with multiple e-mails, as I know. I've only one account on stackexchange for nearly two years. I still get the same error though, amazing. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, there is a third orhan torun: [profile here](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/87797/orhan-torun). I remember the abusive one, and that's not the one linked here.

Comment: @Aaron The one you mentioned is the second one actually. If I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @orhantorun I don't know the order, but there were three altogether: you, the one linked above, and the abusive one, which has been deleted.

Answer (score 3):

After going back and forth with a CM this is our current understanding. The SE system tracks your membership on the network even if you delete a profile on one of the sites. It seems that you have previously had a profile here on Music based on our system records. It's possible that you forgot, as it was a few months ago or that you weren't aware that the profiles were connected, which is understandable as our system can be somewhat complex.

Unfortunately, it seems that your profile was not in good standing when it was deleted and, as such, a system process has automatically added a rate limit to the re-created profile. This was not done by a moderator or staff member. It is a recidivism prevention measure that is built into the system. While this system occasionally catches a handful of relatively innocent askers, it isn't something a mod or CM can override.

Your account is rate limited to one question per week due to this process but it is temporary. If you keep asking questions in good standing (positive scoring that will not be closed), the rate limit will dissipate when the system has more data.

Also as a side note while it may be tempting, please don't get around it by creating a second account.

Comment: Thank you Dom. I do not accept that it was 'my' account. It was not. What if a 3rd 'orhan torun' will create an account on one of the stackexchange subdomains? This is not logical. You claim that the process can't be overridden, obviously nothing to do on your side, but I strictly claim that this is not fair and not logical.

Comment: @orhantorun  I can give a few more details in a private chatroom if you want, but the basic idea is this: your SE account made a music SE account previously and requested it be deleted in July.

Comment: No, I also checked my inbox. There must be related e-mails about this but there is none and I'm a hundred percent sure I use the same account for 14 months. I'd be glad if you provide more information in the chatroom.